# Wordpress redirect to login page if user is not logged in

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to force users to login before they can see browse my site. For new users Access should only be allowed to the `my-account` page which is my login url i.e. `example.org/my-account`

Below is what i've done so far

```
 add_action('wp','force_register' ); 
 function force_register() {
    $loggedin = is_user_logged_in();
    $pagename = get_query_var('pagename'); //get current page name

    if(strcmp("my-account",$pagename) != 0){ //if the user is looking at any other page other than my-account page
        if(!$loggedin){ //if the user is not logged in
            wp_safe_redirect( "/my-account", 302 ); //redirect to the login page
            exit; 

        }

}
```

The browser can't redirect and complains about too many redirects

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Before WordPress does any routing, processing, or handling. It is run in the main() WP method in which the $query_args are passed to parse_request(), as well as when send_headers() , query_posts(), handle_404(), and register_globals() are setup. This is caused for your issue, You may use init instead of wp hook. [more about wp hook.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp/)